# Sidecar proxy in nomad/consul cluster doesn't work

Tags: consul, envoyproxy, nomad, servicemesh, sidecar

Envoy sidecar proxy and terminating gateway deployed within my nomad tasks doesn't work.

```
[2023-10-03 13:32:50.415][1][info][admin] [source/server/admin/admin.cc:66] admin address: 127.0.0.2:19001
[2023-10-03 13:32:50.416][1][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:131] loading tracing configuration
[2023-10-03 13:32:50.416][1][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:91] loading 0 static secret(s)
[2023-10-03 13:32:50.416][1][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:97] loading 1 cluster(s)
[2023-10-03 13:32:50.467][1][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:101] loading 0 listener(s)
[2023-10-03 13:32:50.467][1][info][config] [source/server/configuration_impl.cc:113] loading stats configuration
[2023-10-03 13:32:50.468][1][info][runtime] [source/common/runtime/runtime_impl.cc:463] RTDS has finished initialization
[2023-10-03 13:32:50.468][1][info][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:221] cm init: initializing cds
[2023-10-03 13:32:50.468][1][warning][main] [source/server/server.cc:802] there is no configured limit to the number of allowed active connections. Set a limit via the runtime key overload.global_downstream_max_connections
[2023-10-03 13:32:50.469][1][info][main] [source/server/server.cc:923] starting main dispatch loop
[2023-10-03 13:33:29.302][1][warning][config] [./source/common/config/grpc_stream.h:191] DeltaAggregatedResources gRPC config stream to local_agent closed since 38s ago: 14, upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: immediate connect error: No such file or directory
[2023-10-03 13:33:45.667][1][warning][config] [./source/common/config/grpc_stream.h:191] DeltaAggregatedResources gRPC config stream to local_agent closed since 55s ago: 14, upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: immediate connect error: No such file or directory
[2023-10-03 13:34:08.535][1][warning][config] [./source/common/config/grpc_stream.h:191] DeltaAggregatedResources gRPC config stream to local_agent closed since 78s ago: 14, upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: immediate connect error: No such file or directory
[2023-10-03 13:34:16.799][1][warning][config] [./source/common/config/grpc_stream.h:191] DeltaAggregatedResources gRPC config stream to local_agent closed since 86s ago: 14, upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: immediate connect error: No such file or directory
[2023-10-03 13:34:17.366][1][warning][config] [./source/common/config/grpc_stream.h:191] DeltaAggregatedResources gRPC config stream to local_agent closed since 86s ago: 14, upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: immediate connect error: No such file or directory
```

I'm facing an issue with sidecar proxy in a cluster with TLS enabled. In a situation, where I try to deploy a service, which should be connected via terminating gateway to a service, which is outside the service mesh. I have registered an external service, then I have deployed a job with a terminating gateway service and with my service which i want to deploy with a sidecar proxy.

Nomad job:

```
job "testaccount1" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type = "service"

  group "gateway" {
    network {
      mode = "bridge"
    }

    service {
      name = "sso-gateway"

      connect {
        gateway {
          proxy {}
          }
          terminating {
            service {
              name = "sso"
            }
          }
        }
        sidecar_task {
          config {
            image = "xxxxxxxxxxx/library/envoy"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  group "testaccount1" {
    count = 1

    network {
      mode = "bridge"
      port "http" {
        to = 8080
        static = 8080
      }
    }

    service {
      name = "testaccount1"
      port = "http"
      provider = "consul"

      connect {
        sidecar_service {
            proxy {
                upstreams {
                    destination_name = "sso"
                        local_bind_port = 443
                   }
               }
        }
        sidecar_task {
          config {
            image = "xxxxxxxxxx/library/envoy"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    task "testaccount1" {
      driver = "docker"
      env {
      }
      config {
        image = "xxxxxxxxx/account"
        ports = ["http"]

        auth {
          username = xxxxx
          password = xxxxx
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

nomad server config

```
datacenter = "dc1"
data_dir = "/opt/nomad/data"
bind_addr = "0.0.0.0"

server {
  enabled = true
  bootstrap_expect = 3
  encrypt = "xxxxxxxxxx"
}

tls {
  http = true
  rpc  = true

  ca_file   = "/etc/pki/nomad/nomad-agent-ca.pem"
  cert_file = "/etc/pki/nomad/global-server-nomad.pem"
  key_file  = "/etc/pki/nomad/global-server-nomad-key.pem"

  verify_server_hostname = true
  verify_https_client    = true
}

client {
  enabled = false
}

consul {
  address = "127.0.0.1:8501"
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  grpc_ca_file = "/etc/pki/consul/consul-agent-ca.pem"
  grpc_address = "127.0.0.1:8503"
  ca_file      = "/etc/pki/consul/consul-agent-ca.pem"
  cert_file    = "/etc/pki/consul/dc1-server-consul-1.pem"
  key_file     = "/etc/pki/consul/dc1-server-consul-1-key.pem"
  ssl          = true
}

acl {
  enabled = true
}
```

consul server config

```
data_dir = "/opt/consul"

node_name = "server2"

client_addr = "0.0.0.0"
bind_addr = "10.4.5.22"
advertise_addr = "10.4.5.22"

encrypt = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
encrypt_verify_incoming = true
encrypt_verify_outgoing = true

ui_config {
  enabled = true
}

rejoin_after_leave = true

verify_incoming = true
verify_outgoing = true
verify_server_hostname = true
ca_file = "/etc/pki/consul/consul-agent-ca.pem"
cert_file = "/etc/pki/consul/dc1-server-consul-1.pem"
key_file = "/etc/pki/consul/dc1-server-consul-1-key.pem"

ports = {
  https = 8501
  http = 8500
  grpc = 8502
  grpc_tls = 8503
  dns = -1
}

acl {
  enabled = true
  default_policy = "deny"
  tokens {
    default = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}


server = true
bootstrap_expect = 3

log_level = "DEBUG"
log_file = "/var/log/consul/"
log_rotate_max_files = 30
```

```
Nomad v1.6.2
BuildDate 2023-09-13T16:47:25Z
Revision 73e372ad94033db2ceaf53468b270a31544c23fd
```

```
Consul v1.16.2
Revision 68f81912
Build Date 2023-09-19T19:29:18Z
```